# ASLR and DEP in Delphi, How to tell?

Tags: delphi, portable-executable, aslr, dep

From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michael_howard/archive/2007/04/04/codegear-s-new-delphi-2007-supports-aslr-and-nx.aspx,
I am using {$SETPEOPTFLAGS $140} in my project file right under the program name to get address space layout randomization (ASLR) and DEP.

How can one tell if the flags are set in the PE?  PeStudio seems to have the info, but doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way that I know is to use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) on the running app.  Just double-click on the process and read it out of this dialog:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Need to add both header inside the application project file:

{$SETPEOPTFLAGS $140}   //add this line

{$SetPEOptFlags $140}   //and this line

between begin and end.